# Texture's transparency is sometimes ignored

Tags: android, textures, opengl-es-2.0, google-cardboard

I've developing an OpenGLES 2.0 application on Android, and have textures mapped to some of my objects. These textures are created from bitmaps that have transparent bits, but when rendered sometimes the transparent bits are truly transparent and sometimes they're black

[image: Black is the new transparent]

[image: Transparent is actually transparent]

In both cases, I use identical texture creation and shader code.

Here's the texture loading...

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), id);
// If something went wrong delete the texture and return 0
if (bitmap == null) {
    return 0;
}


final int[] textureID = new int[1];
GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureID, 0);

GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID[0]);

GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

// Copy the bitmap to the texture
android.opengl.GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

// Unbind
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

I render with the following

```
GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

// Prepare the coordinate data
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
        mPositionParam, Mesh.XYZ_COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
        GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
        Mesh.XYZ_COORDS_PER_VERTEX * Mesh.BYTES_PER_FLOAT, mesh.getVertexBuffer());

// Set the active texture unit to texture unit 0.
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);

// Bind the texture to this unit.
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mesh.getTextureId());

// Tell the texture uniform sampler to use this texture in the shader by binding to texture unit 0.
GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureParam, 0);

FloatBuffer textureBuffer = useAltTexture && mesh.hasStereoTexture() ?
        mesh.getStereoTextureBuffer() : mesh.getTextureBuffer();
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
        mTexturePosParam, Mesh.UV_COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
        GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
        Mesh.UV_COORDS_PER_VERTEX * Mesh.BYTES_PER_FLOAT, textureBuffer);


GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mModelViewProjectionParam, 1, false, modelViewProjection, 0);
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
// Draw the shape
GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, mesh.getVertexCount());
GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
```

My vertex shader:

```
uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;

attribute vec4 a_Position;
attribute vec2 a_TexCoord;

varying vec2 v_TexCoord;

void main() {
    // The matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position.
    // Note that the u_MVPMatrix factor *must be first* in order
    // for the matrix multiplication product to be correct.
    v_TexCoord = a_TexCoord;
    gl_Position = u_MVPMatrix * a_Position;
}
```

My Fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 v_TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D u_Texture;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoord);
}
```

Any clues as to why blending is inconsistent?

Comment: Did you use only one same blending option for them?

Comment: @SungWoo I use the same blending option for all the textures. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: If you draw the back one after the front one,  pixels behind the front image are not processed

Comment: @SungWoo can you clarify your comment - does draw order matter? In general there's no guarantee which one will appear closer.

Comment: draw order matters if  it's with translucent (not completely transparent) polygons

Comment: you're right @SungWoo, rendering order does matter. If you'd like to post an answer explaining why, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because transparent pixels still create depth buffer entries, you have to follow [painter's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter%27s_algorithm)

However, you can discard the pixel in glsl using a "**discard**" keyword.

```
 if (color.rgb == vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0)) 
  discard;
else
  fragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
```